# Can I use LastLoginDate standard field to determine users who log in to Community for the first time?

Tags: user, login, user-management

I checked the documentation for the [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) object and didn't find any explanation on how the `LastLoginDate` is managed. The description was not helpful:

> **LastLoginDate**
>
> The date and time when the user last successfully logged in. This
>   value is updated if 60 seconds have elapsed since the user’s last
>   login.

So my question is can I rely on the `LastLoginDate` field to determine when the user logs in to Community for the first time. My goal is to redirect users who log in for the first time to their profiles pages. If the value in `LastLoginDate` is blank it means that the user has never logged in to Community and they should be redirected to the profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `LastLoginDate` works the same for community users as it does for standard users.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use login history for all successful and failed login attempts for organizations and enabled portals.

If entry is not there, it means user has never tried for login.